# Computing real integrals using the Residue Theorem where singularities are on the real line

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

How would you compute, for $a>0$ the integral $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x(x^2 + a^2)} dx \, \, ?$$

I've computed the residues of the function $$f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{z(z^2 + a^2)} $$ which I got, for the poles at $z = 0, ia, -ia$ residues of $\frac{1}{a^2}, \frac{-e^{-a}}{2a^2}, \frac{-e^a}{2a^2}$ respectively. But I'm now stuck as they are all on the real line? How could I used the residue formula to compute this?

Comment: That integral is a function of $a$, not of $z$, so its residues, if any, would be values of $a$. You probably mean the residues of the integrand?

Comment: Ah yeah thank you, that was a mistake, I have edited accordingly

Comment: You have $\int_0^\inf \frac{\sin(x)/x}{x^2+a^2}$. The function $\sin(x)/x$ does not have a pole at $x=0$ (strictly speaking it's undefined at $x=0$ but it has a holomorphic extension that includes the origin). So there are only two poles, $ia$ and $-ia$, both of which are not on the real line.

Answer (score 2):

The poles at $\pm\mathrm ia$ aren't on the real line. To avoid integrating over a pole at the origin, use

$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x(x^2+a^2)}\mathrm dx=\frac12\Im\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\mathrm e^{\mathrm ix}-1}{x(x^2+a^2)}\mathrm dx\;.
$$

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can use a path with goes from $-M$ to $-\frac{1}{M}$ along the real line (path $\gamma_1$), then along a circle with radius $\frac{1}{M}$ around $0$ to $\frac{1}{M}$ (path $\gamma_2$), continues along the real line to $M$ (path $\gamma_3$) and finally goes back to $-M$ (path $\gamma_4$) along a circle of radius $M$ around $0$.

If you can for example find a bound for $f$ along the small circle $\gamma_2$ independent of $M$ (for sufficiently large $M$ suffices of course), then you know that the integral along $\gamma_2$ goes to zero as $M \to \infty$. Since $\frac{sin(x)}{x} \to 1$ as $x \to 0$, such a bound should exist.

That leaves you with having to shows that the integral along $\gamma_4$ goes to zero too, e.g by showing that $f$ is bounded by $\frac{C}{|z|^2}$ for some $C$ (for sufficiently large $|z|$, of course). If that is the case, the integral is bounded by $\frac{C}{M^2}\pi M$, since $\pi M$ is the length of the arc with radius $M$ around 0, and  the integral thus goes to 0 as $M \to \infty$. The fact that the denominator is a polynomial in $x$ of degree 3 should provide you with such a bound.

Comment: I keep seeing answers to these sorts of questions that propose taking limits of circles around the origin, which makes me wonder: Do you prefer this method to that of subtracting out the pole, or are you not aware of the latter? This seems more complicated to my mind.

Comment: @joriki I prefer it, because (to me) its more obvious what's going on. The other way is shorter, but to me always feels a bit like magic. I was never any good at "seeing" algebraic tricks, so whenever possible I resort to geometric intuition.

Comment: Thanks. It's always good to be reminded how different mathematical tastes can be :-) (To my mind, evaluating real integrals using complex contours at infinity already feels maximally like magic; it could hardly seem more magical just from tweaking the numerator a little :-)